# Is it possible to display other column names from two table to one table by using join clause by using foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Good day Sir/Ma'am, I need help regarding on Join clause is it possible to use join clause in multiple column names from other table with foreign key?
Problem: I have table named
Table 1: 'biditem'
COL.1: biditemid(pk)
COL.2: user_id(fk)
COL.3: product_id(fk)
COL.4: bidamountprice (decimal)
COL.5: bidtime (datetime)

Table 2: 'user'
COL.1: user_id(pk)
COL.2: user_firstname (varchar)
COL.3: user_middlename (varchar)
COL.4: user_lastname (varchar)

Table 3: 'product'
COL.1: product_id(pk)
COL.2: product_name varchar(25)

I want to display from the biditem look like this in php
[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what a JOIN is for. What have you tried, and what problem are you having?

Comment: SELECT users.user_firstname, user.user_middlename, user.user_lastname,
product.product_name FROM biditem 
(INNER JOIN users ON biditem.user_id = users.user_firstname,users.users_middlename,users.users_lastname)
(INNER JOIN product ON biditem.product_id = product.product_name)

here's my query Sir but it when execute it has no display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write your query like

```
select 
   b.biditemid, 
   concat(u.user_firstname,' ',u.user_middle,' ',u.user_lastname) as name, 
   p.product_name,
   b.bidamountprice, 
   b.bidtime
from 
   bitem b,
   user u,
   product p
where
   b.user_id=u.user_id
   and b.product_id=p.product_id
```

- name your table with alias `short form`
- always remember for joining if you have 3 tables then 3-1 will be your minimum `where` clauses to make proper join with your all tables
- likewise you had 3 tables so the minimum number or where clause use was 2 in your above code.

You can use that standard and you can use left inner, outer join too whatever you are comfort in. Both standards can be use in oracle sqlplus, mySql, postgreSql

Comment: Good day Sir, I have follow up question?  regarding on WHERE clause what if i want to display all the same product name on the table biditem'?

Comment: like if you want to display the list of bids for example who's product name starts with    
 **B** then your query will be same and you need to add one more where clause like below.
`select 
   b.biditemid, 
   concat(u.user_firstname,' ',u.user_middle,' ',u.user_lastname) as name, 
   p.product_name,
   b.bidamountprice, 
   b.bidtime
from 
   bitem b,
   user u,
   product p
where
   b.user_id=u.user_id
   and b.product_id=p.product_id
   and p.product_name like '%B'`

Comment: Sir I need your help again, how to select query displaying the specific use who have highest bid ? Here's my query 
select 
   b.biditemid, 
   concat(u.user_firstname,' ',u.user_middle,' ',u.user_lastname) as name, 
   p.product_name,
   MAX(b.bidamountprice), 
   b.bidtime
from 
   bitem b,
   user u,
   product p
where
   b.user_id=u.user_id
   and b.product_id=p.product_id


PROBLEM: Is there when I input higher price that the other one with using another name is the name is not displaying match by their amount price and datetime

Comment: why you use max(b.bidamountprice)??? if you want max bid amount and need one complete record . then your query should be like.     `select b.biditemid, concat(u.user_firstname,' ',u.user_middle,' ',u.user_lastname) as name, p.product_name, b.bidamountprice, b.bidtime from bitem b, user u, product p where b.user_id=u.user_id and b.product_id=p.product_id order by b.bidamountprice desc limit 1`

Comment: It work! Thank you so much Sir!!! I thought using MAX is the right query for getting highest bid?

Comment: max is a sql function use max(column name) without any other column along with it then you will get the result with single colum and single row. this is same as count or sum function..

Answer (score 0):

The 2 tables mentioned do have relationships between them so you can try like - using aliases to refer to the tables to make things clearer.

```
select 
    b.`biditemid`,
    concat(u.`user_firstname`,' ',u.`user_middle`,' ',u.`user_lastname`) as `Name`, 
    p.`product_name` as `Product Name`,
    b.`bidamountprice` as `Bid Amount`,
    b.`bidtime` as `DateTime`
from `bititem` b
    left outer join `user` u on u.`user_id`=b.`user_id`
    left outer join `product` p on p.`product_id`=b.`product_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
bi.biditemid,
CONCAT(u.user_firstname, ' ', u.user_middle, ' ',u.user_lastname) AS Name,
p.product_name as "Pruduct Name",
bi.bidamountprice as "Bid Amount", 
bi.bidtime as Datetime
from biditem as bi left join user as u on bi.user_id = u.user_id
left join product as p on bi.product_id = p.product_id
```

add where condition as you needed after that.